# Inserting(saving) data from two forms into database winforms sql db

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, insert

I am developing a small pos application where user can make payments and save it into db. Until now I stored data from one form(datagridview, textboxes etc), but now I decided to add one more form (for handling payments). The idea is that the user call data from db in datagridview(***barcode, qty, name, price, total, vat et***c) , then press the btnpayment(***opens the 2nd form***), then the user give the the required data(give payment), then after clicking the pay button the data from two forms should be inserted into sql table
Now I want to save data from two forms into sql db in same time using same stored procedures.

Before adding the 2nd form I used this code to insert data:

```
    try
    {
    conn.Open();


    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgartikuj.Rows)
    {
    if (!row.IsNewRow)
    {
    SqlCommand commandinsert= new SqlCommand("insertfaturimi", conn);
    commandinsert.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    commandinsert.Parameters.Clear();
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nr", int.Parse(txtnr.Text)));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@client", cmbclient.Text));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@subtotal", txtsubtotal.Text));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@discount", txtdiscount.Text));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@total", txttotal.Text));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vatvalue", txtvatvalue.Text));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@productnr", prodnr.Text));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@seller", lbluser.Text));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@time", DateTime.Now));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@barcode", row.Cells[0].Value));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", row.Cells[1].Value));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@qty", row.Cells[2].Value));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vat", row.Cells[4].Value));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@price", row.Cells[3].Value));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totalpcs", row.Cells[5].Value));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vatvalueswithoutvatpcs", row.Cells[6].Value));
    commandinsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vatvaluepcs", row.Cells[7].Value));
    commandinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }


    }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Failed" + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
    conn.Close();
    }
```

The 2nd form has some textboxes (payments and change). Now upper code I want to put into 2nd form pay button , but don't know how to link two forms together. My question is what should I change in upper code to be able to put in 2nd form insert button, then insert 2 forms in same time(form one with products detailed)  and (second form with payments details)

I added this class code

```
        public class arka_data
    {
        public int NR { get; set; }
        public int BARKODI { get; set; }
        public string EMERTIMI { get; set; }
        public int SASIA {get;set;}
        public float CMIMI {get;set;}
        public float TVSH { get; set; }
        public float TOTAL { get; set; }
        public float NENTOTALI { get; set; }
        public float ZBRITJA { get; set; }
        public float TOTALI { get; set; }
        public DateTime KOHA { get; set; }
        public string KASIERI { get; set; }
        public string KLIENTI { get; set; }
        public float VLERAETVSH { get; set; }
        public float VLERAPATVSH { get; set; }
        public int NRATIKUJVE { get; set; }
        public float TOTALIPCS { get; set; }
        public float VLERATVSHTOTAL { get; set; }


    }
    arka_data dta = new arka_data();
    public void mbushe(string[] args)
    {

       for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
          dta.NR = int.Parse(txtnrfatures.Text);
          dta.VLERATVSHTOTAL = float.Parse( textBox1.Text);
          dta.BARKODI = int.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString());
          dta.EMERTIMI = dataTable.Rows[i][1].ToString();
          dta.SASIA = int.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][2].ToString());
          dta.CMIMI = int.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][3].ToString());
          dta.TVSH = int.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][4].ToString());
          dta.NENTOTALI = float.Parse(txttotali.Text);
          dta.ZBRITJA = float.Parse(txtzbritja.Text);
          dta.TOTALI = float.Parse(totali.Text);
          dta.KOHA = DateTime.Now;
          dta.KASIERI = lbluser.Text;
          dta.KLIENTI = cmbklienti.Text;
          dta.VLERAETVSH = float.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][7].ToString());
          dta.VLERAPATVSH = float.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][6].ToString());
          dta.NRATIKUJVE = int.Parse(lblnumri.Text);
          dta.TOTALIPCS = float.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][5].ToString());
```

But don't know how to call the method on form2

Comment: you can add the data to the 2nd form, in the form, set these data, then when 2nd form close, refer the data from the 1st form, save them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. I assume you need least coding. So the way which is done in an enterprise environment could be different.

Instead of calling a stored procedure from the first form, create an object from a class which holds data of all data elements in the first form.

Pass that object to the second form.
Then create the object with the second form.

Create a separate class for your database access and execute ADO.Net (things like what you wrote here).

Use the 2 objects, create the DB Commands and execute

Comment: @i created the class also the object from the class, but now I cant call that method. P.S I updated the question , I added the code part of the class.

Comment: If you were to learn , make the classes smaller and first try to understand the concept. Then apply that to the lengthy code. Otherwise, its hard to go through a lengthy code.

Comment: In your case, you can create the class, out side of both forms and to be accessed as public. Then have a property in the Form2 which is of the type of that class. 
Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210717/pass-value-from-parent-form-to-child-form